# Binding select query data to viewmodel list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to bind select query data to my viewmodel. Can anybody suggest how to replace the question marks? I need to add an item to `List<FItemVM>` for each FItemVM.

**ViewModel**

```
public class FListVM
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime Posted { get; set; }
    public List<FItemVM> FItemVMs { get; set; }
}
    public class FItemVM
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int FItemSum { get; set; }
    }
```

**Controller**

```
var fListItem = db.FListItems.Include(f => f.FList)
                             .Include(f => f.FItem)
                             .Select(f => new FListVM
                                {
                                    Title = f.FList.Title,
                                    Posted = f.FList.Posted,
                                    FItemVMs = new List<FItemVM>()
                                    {
                                        ???
                                    }
                                }).OrderByDescending(f => f.Posted).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a collection, you can add it as follows

```
var fListItem = db.FListItems.Include(f => f.FList)
                             .Include(f => f.FItem)
                             .Select(f => new FListVM
                                {
                                    Title = f.FList.Title,
                                    Posted = f.FList.Posted,
                                    FItemVMs = f.FList.Where(fl=>fl.Title==f.FList.Title).Select(fl=>f.FList.Items).ToList()
                                }).OrderByDescending(f => f.Posted).ToList();
```

HTH

Comment: That will just add two `FItemVMs`, won't it? I probably should have said that the number of `FItemVMs` will vary. I tried using `foreach` and `add` but couldn't figure out the correct syntax

Comment: I have updated to take the FItemVMs from FList, guessing that the FList will have a collection of FItems